# How to find out which processes consume most energy on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance, battery

In Linux, is it possible to know which processes consume most battery energy at the moment?

Comment: Processes don't directly consume battery energy. They do by wasting CPU time, mostly. Take a look at `top`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, [powertop](http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/). Look at the screenshot:

[image: powertop]

But powertop hasn't 100% precision, CPU isn't the only battery consumer. Use also [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) for the disk activity.

Comment: thanks, wakeups-from-idle per second should be a small number - 17.4 on the picture, in my case it's 800-900. most wakeups are caused from network card(which is needed) and SingalSender - which should come from Chromium, but I don't have Chromium. what should I reduce the number of wakeups?

Comment: Try with ethernet and wifi disconnected. Close all software. Look at powertop again. If the problem persist may be a bug in the kernel.